# Interaction marginal effects plot with overlay histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to create an interaction marginal effects plot where the histogram of the predictor is in the background of the plot. The issue is somewhat complicated since the marginal effects plot is also faceted. I would like the end result to look like something the MARHIS package does in Stata. In case of continuous predictors, I just use `geom_rug`, but that does not work with factors. I would like to use `geom_histogram` but I run into a scaling problem:

```
ggplot(newdat, aes(cenretrosoc, linetype = factor(wave))) +
    geom_line(aes(y = cengovrec), size=0.8) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "twodash", "solid")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = plo,
                  group=factor(wave)), linetype =3) +
    geom_line(aes(y = phi,
                  group=factor(wave)), linetype =3) +
    facet_grid(. ~ regioname) +
    xlab("Economy") +
    ylab("Disapproval of Record") +
    labs(linetype='Wave') +
    theme_minimal()
```

which works, and produces this graph: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n1YC.png)

However, when I add the histogram bit

```
+   geom_histogram(aes(cenretrosoc), position="identity", linetype=1,
                   fill="gray60", data = data, alpha=0.5)
```

this is what happens:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2xXX.png)

I think it's because of the different scales the predicted probabilities and the histogram has on the Y axis. But I am not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Here's a reproducible example to illustrate the issue (it needs the WWGbook package for the data it uses)

```
# install.packages("WWGbook")
# install.packages("lme4")
# install.packages("ggplot2")
require("WWGbook")
require("lme4")
require("ggplot2")
# checking the dataset
head(classroom)

# specifying the model
model <- lmer(mathgain ~ yearstea*sex*minority
              + (1|schoolid/classid), data=classroom)

# dataset for prediction
newdat <- expand.grid(
  mathgain  = 0,
  yearstea  = seq(min(classroom$yearstea, rm=TRUE),
                  max(classroom$yearstea, rm=TRUE),
                  5),
  minority    = seq(0, 1, 1),
  sex = seq(0,1,1))

mm <- model.matrix(terms(model), newdat)

## calculating the predictions

newdat$mathgain <- predict(model, 
                            newdat, re.form = NA)
pvar1 <- diag(mm %*% tcrossprod(vcov(model), mm))

## Calculating lower and upper CI
cmult <- 1.96
newdat <- data.frame(
  newdat, plo = newdat$mathgain - cmult*sqrt(pvar1), 
  phi = newdat$mathgain + cmult*sqrt(pvar1))

## this is the plot of fixed effects uncertainty

marginaleffect <- ggplot(newdat, aes(yearstea, linetype = factor(sex))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mathgain), size=0.8) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "twodash")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = plo,
                group=factor(sex)), linetype =3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = phi,
                group=factor(sex)), linetype =3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ minority) +
  xlab("First grade teacher years of teaching experience") +
  ylab("Predicted Probability of student gain in math") +
  labs(linetype='Sex') +
  theme_minimal()
```

As one can see `marginaleffect` is a plot of marginal effects :) Now I want to add the histogram to the background, so I write:

```
marginaleffect + geom_histogram(aes(yearstea), position="identity", linetype=1,
                                fill="gray60", data = classroom, alpha=0.5)
```

It does add the histogram, but it overwrites the OY scale with the histogram values. In this example one can still see the effects as the original predicted probabilities scale was comparable to the frequencies. However, in my case, a data-set with many values, this is not the case.

Preferably I would not have any scale for the histogram shown. It should just have a maximum which is the predicted probabilities scale maximum, so it covers the same area, but it does not overwrite the pred prob values on the vertical axis.

Comment: Please, add a dataset, to make it easier to help you. If it is a probleme of scale, you could normalize the data, so they are between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post out: https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2

I followed the steps and was able to get the following plot:

[image]

Also, note that I've added `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` to make histograms start from the x-axis.

```
m1 <- marginaleffect + geom_line(aes(y = mathgain), size=0.8) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "twodash")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = plo,
                  group=factor(sex)), linetype =3) +
    geom_line(aes(y = phi,
                  group=factor(sex)), linetype =3)

m2 <- marginaleffect + geom_histogram(aes(yearstea), position="identity", linetype=1,
                                fill="gray60", data = classroom, alpha=0.5, bins = 30) +
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))


g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(m1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(m2))

library(gtable)

pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
# The link uses g2$grobs[[...]] but it doesn't seem to work... single bracket works, on the other hand....
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

library(grid)
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was an issue with my objects in the memory (I can't delete my comments though). I managed to customize the plot to a large extent, so this is the final result: [https://s9.postimg.org/716vpolr3/stack.png](plot) I just still have one more issue, I would like to ask you about. Something strange is happening with the X axis line. Do you have any suggestion to correct the pattern variation and leave only the solid line? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: histogram <- econ_effect + geom_histogram(aes(as.numeric(cenretrosoc)), position="identity", linetype=1, fill="gray80", colour = "gray80", data = data, alpha=0.2, bins = 15) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="transparent",colour=NA), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(econ_effect))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(histogram))
pp<-c(subset(g1$layout, name=="panel", se=t:r))
g<-gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[which(g2$layout$name=="panel")], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)
grid.draw(g)

Comment: @Endre I can't really figure out what's causing the issue without looking at the data. Are those dotted lines on the axis present when you try to plot them independently?